# Sublime text 3 build 3083 Run variant not chosen automatically

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3 for C++ development. I just updated from previous build of Sublime Text 3 to the current one (build 3083). The only thing that bothers me is that whenever I try to "Run" a C++ program, using Command+Shift+B (OS X), instead of running the build, it comes up with a menu from which I have to choose the configuration, such as

- C++ Single File
- C++ Single File - Run
- My custom C++
- My custom C++ - Run

It is quite annoying, and the previous Sublime 3 didn't do this (it was able to automatically select the right configuration). The problem does not appear on building (Command + B), but only on trying to run the build with Command + Shift +B.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this problem too, and digging through [this thread](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17471&start=40) helped me figure out what was going on.

The old behavior of <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> executing the primary build system command, and <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd> executing the first *variant* has changed. Now the latter always shows the command palette with all build systems that are applicable. Once you've selected the variant you want to run from the palette then subsequent <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> will re-run the same variant until you use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd> to select another variant.

I tested two different ways to revert to the old behavior, both involve adding a custom keyboard binding

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": false} }
```

or

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Run"} }
```

(in the second case replace `Run` with whatever your variant name is)

The linked thread also says you can specify a path to the *sublime-build* file

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"build_system": "Packages/ALanguage/ALanguage.sublime-build", variant": "Run"} }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `ctrl + b` will then run the variant selected with `ctrl + shift +b`. Or at least that's what happens with me. I have to force to select the build system. This is of course, the intended work flow as proposed by the [developer](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17471) but it's a pain that you can't have the old behaviour with regards to this. It'd be nice to have ctrl + shift + b just run the "Run" variant of the last used build system instead.

Comment: @Rapptz same here, still much much better than the default. I **hate** the modification brought with 3083, I wonder how likes it...

Comment: @vsoftco I actually decided to try and stick with the new behavior in the hope I'll get used to it, but hasn't happened yet :) Haven't had a chance to test what @Rapptz says in his comment, but it looks like the other answer has the solution that reverts `Ctrl+B` also to the previous behavior.

Comment: @vsoftco I've gotten used to it already but it is a shame. My new workflow is just to do `ctrl + shift + b` to run and then switch back to compile. Chances are you can have a simple plugin that does the 'run' aspect if I was desperate enough.

Comment: @Rapptz yeah, exactly, it is a shame (of course, our opinions may be biased, but in general I appreciate quality and this seems like a step down). The things that drives me crazy is that the annoying menu pops onto the screen (default behaviour), and I have to manually select something.

Answer (score 2):

```
    {
        "keys": ["super+b"], 
        "command": "build",
        "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.c++" }
        ], 
        "args": {
            "build_system": "Packages/C++/C++.sublime-build",
            "variant": "Build"
        }
    },

    {
        "keys": ["super+shift+b"], 
        "command": "build",
        "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.c++" }
        ],
        "args": {
            "build_system": "Packages/C++/C++.sublime-build",
            "variant": "Run"
        }
    },

    {
        "keys": ["super+b"], 
        "command": "build",
        "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.java" }
        ], 
        "args": {
            "build_system": "Packages/Java/Java.sublime-build",
            "variant": "Build"
        }
    },

    {
        "keys": ["super+shift+b"], 
        "command": "build",
        "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.java" }
        ],
        "args": {
            "build_system": "Packages/Java/Java.sublime-build",
            "variant": "Run"
        }
    }
```

Adding this in Key Bindings-User restored old behavior for me. Hope this helps.

EDIT : Using 'context' we can have the same short-cut keys build for multiple languages, & any undefined build_systems in key bindings will have default behaviour for the keys.

Comment: Great, it works (in a sense), thanks much! The only issue is that when you choose other build system, the keys are bounded to the C++ compile command.

Comment: Yup thats an issue. I guess a plugin should do the job. I'll post the link here if I am able to make one to restore the old behaviour.

Comment: @vsoftco : check out the edited asnwer, this should do the exact thing you asked. Let me know how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile and run you program in sublime text 3 
with different - different key (like "f5" for compile and "f6" for run on
command prompt then following my steps.

1- in sublime text 3 just click preferences > Key Bindings.
2- here is opened a new window in two set 1set by default key-binding on left.
   2set is user defined panel an empty panel
3- now paste the following code.

```
[
{ "keys": ["f5"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": ""} },
{ "keys": ["f6"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Run"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"select":false} }

]
```

Now you can compile with "f5" and "f6" for run.
You can change the key as you want by replacing keys.